# byte array getter setter in C# asp.net

Tags: arrays, byte, setter, getter

i am taking bytes array from file upload control and saving them in a class object but i am getting exception of stackoverflow infinite loop or recursive like sonmething.

my code is:

```
public class UploadDetail
{`enter code here`
    //public bool IsReady { get; set; }
    public string FileSize { get; set; }
    //public int UploadedLength { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileinBytes;


    public byte[] FileBytes
    {
        get
        {
            return FileBytes;
        }

        set
        {                
            FileBytes = value;
        }
    }
```

here is my gridview button event where i am setting the objects value:

```
 protected void gvUploadFiles_Clicked(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {    
         if (e.CommandName == "doingUpload")
         {

             int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

             GridViewRow row = gvUploadFiles.Rows[index];

             if (gvUploadFiles.DataKeys[index]["FileName"] != null)
             {
                 currentUpload.FileName = gvUploadFiles.DataKeys[index]["FileName"].ToString();
             }

             if (gvUploadFiles.DataKeys[index]["FileSize"] != null)
             {
                 currentUpload.FileSize = gvUploadFiles.DataKeys[index]["FileSize"].ToString();
             }


             if (gvUploadFiles.DataKeys[index]["FileBytes"] == null)
             {
                 currentUpload.FileBytes=(byte[])gvUploadFiles.DataKeys[index]["UploadDetail.FileBytes()"];
                 //currentUpload.FileBytes(row.FindControl("fileBytes"));
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an infinite recursion in your getter/setter.

Do you want to write it to `FileinBytes`?

```
public byte[] FileBytes
{
    get
    {
        return FileinBytes;
    }

    set
    {
        FileinBytes = value;
    }
}
```

An alternative could be to use an auto implemented property:

```
public byte[] FileBytes { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanx Peter it worked for me.....:) Thanks a lot i was stucked it in couple of hours ago....:)